# Verificação e Preenchimento de células Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Tenho a seguinte planilha conforme imagem abaixo, gostaria de criar um VBA para verificar se o conteúdo inserido no intervalo de células dessa planilha existe na lista da segunda imagem abaixo, se existir, preencher de verde a célula do conteúdo da imagem 1.

OBS: Não usei formatação condicional porque os números adicionados são sempre arrastados para outras células em algumas revisões do documento.

[image: Planilha onde verificar e preencher células]

[image: Lista onde vou verificar os nomes existentes]

Answer (score 1):

Olá!

Acho que não precisa de VBA para isso, pode usar formatação condicinal da seguinte maneira:

1. Selecione todas as células que deseja colorir, vá em formatação condicional e clique em *Nova Regra*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Selecione a ultima opção *Usar fuma fórmula....*, conforme figura abaixo, insira a fórmula abaixo e clique no botão *Formatar...* e faça a formatação conforme desejar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fórmula:

```
=SE(ÉERROS(PROCV(B5;$D$20:$D$22;1;FALSO));FALSO;VERDADEIRO)
```

> [IMPORTANTE] A parte da fórmula `B5` será sua primeira célula selecionada, notar que na minha imagem de exemplo está na coluna B na linha 5. E retirar o cifrão `$`.
>
> A parte da fórmula `$D$20:$D$22` é onde possui os dados de verificação (sua segunda imagem).

**EDIÇÃO 1**

Segue imagem abaixo como formatar para ficar da forma como sugeriu na pergunta. A tela abaixo aparecerá após clicar em *Formatar...*, clique em Preenchimento e escolha a cor de preenchimento:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Olha a observação que adicionei por favor. Mesmo assim obrigado

Comment: Idependente de arrastar os número essa formatação condicional vai continuar funcionando. E se usar as tabelas do Excel para os dados de validação (código na tabela) ficará melhor ainda.

Comment: Eu seleciono a celula e arrasto pra outra posição.. geralmente quando arrasto, a celula que ficou vazia perde as propriedades

Comment: @GustavoDawson eu testei aqui e não perde ao mover uma célula com o mouse para outra célula... vou tentar fazer um gif e postar na resposta.

Comment: Segue meu modelo https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiqRCjOR1qMHmI4NjHSwUGFqDKZjKA favor notar que estou usando o Excel 2013, contudo creio que até no 2010 tb seja da mesma forma. Chegando em casa posso testar até no 2007 e postarei comentário.

Comment: faça o seguinte teste e você vai ver o problema que encontro: Pegue essa planilha que você me mandou e arraste uma das celulas que contenha "p9" por exemplo, ao arrastas ela continua "verde", mas a celula antiga onde o "p9" estava perde a propriedade, se vc escrever "p9" na celula antiga denovo ele não pinta de verde.

Comment: @GustavoDawson isso só vai acontecer se onde vc está arrastando a célula não tiver com a mesma formatação. Faça o mesmo teste ai arrastando para um local onde tem a mesma formatação desejada e verá que funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que os dados de procura estão na coluna C da Planilha(1) e Você irá procurar na Planilha(2), este é um código com a função .Find

```
Dim Rng As Range, rng2 As Range

ncell = Sheets(1).Cells(Sheets(1).Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    Set Rng = Sheets(2).Cells 'range para procurar
    Set rng2 = Rng(1, 1)

    For j = 1 To ncell
    pesquisar = Sheets(1).Cells(j, 3).Value 'referência de procura na coluna 3 (ou seja, C)
        With Rng
        Set cellFound = .Find(what:=pesquisar, After:=rng2, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not cellFound Is Nothing Then
                FirstAddress = cellFound.Address
                Do
                    Sheets(2).Range(cellFound.Address).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                    Set cellFound = .FindNext(cellFound)
                Loop While Not cellFound Is Nothing And cellFound.Address <> FirstAddress
             End If
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Outra alternativa é a utilização de um Object Dictionary, este é mais rápido e otimiza o tempo de processamento. Recomendado para planilhas com muitos dados.

Comment: Vou testar. Adicionei uma observação na minha pergunta. Muito obrigado desde já

Comment: Este código pinta de verde somente, caso você o mude de endereço. É preciso alterar o código para verificar isto. Como a mudança é realizada? Manualmente?

Comment: Sim, é feita manualmente, seleciona a celula e arrasta pra outra posição.. geralmente quando arrasto, a celula que ficou vazia perde as propriedades

Comment: Bom, você pode alterar para uma lógica do tipo: em mudanças na planilha usada (`Worksheet_Change`), a célula selecionada passa a possuir fundo branco: `Range.Interior.ColorIndex = 2`