# Como pesquisar se valores da coluna A não existem na coluna B?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Por exemplo, tenho uma planilha:

```
  [   A   ] [   B   ]
1  valor1     valor1
2  valor2     valor2
3  valor3     valor3
4  valor4     valor4
5  valor5     valor6
```

Podem ver que, na coluna B, não existe o `valor5`, o que eu queria é achar os valores que tem na coluna A mas não estão na B. Eu ja procurei formulas, etc, nas não consigo fazer isso. Alguém teria ideia de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função que você busca é a **PROCV**

Com a fórmula que coloquei abaixo, você está varrendo o intervalo $A$1:$A$5 em busca do conteúdo que estará na célula marcada no primeiro parâmetro (que no caso é a **B1**). Se não encontrar o valor, ela retornará "*não*".

Coloque essa fórmula na coluna de resultado e arraste pra baixo pra auto completar nas linhas abaixo.

```
=SE.ERRO(PROCV(B1;$A$1:$A$5;1;0);"não")
```

O resultado deverá ser:

```
  [   A   ] [   B   ] [ RESULTADO ]
1  valor1     valor1    =SEERRO(PROCV(B1;$A$1:$A$5;1;0);"não")
2  valor2     valor2     valor2
3  valor2     valor3     não
4  valor4     valor4     valor4
5  valor5     valor6     não
```

[Se precisar de mais detalhes, acesse a documentação que muito bem explicada](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/PROC-Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-PROC-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb)

Comment: O meu está retornando #NOME? na coluna C. Sabe me dizer o por que? Digo coluna C que é a coluna que estou aplicando a formula.

Comment: Isso. Coluna "C" equivale a coluna "resultado" do exemplo acima. Verifique se não é a formatação da célula. Se não for isso, você pode estar colocando a referência onde não se é permitido. Certifique-se de copiar o mesmo valor da formula: `=SE.ERRO(PROCV(B1;$A$1:$A$5;1;0);"não")`  @LucasCarvalho

Comment: Ta dando que a formula contem texto não reconhecido.

Comment: Então vamos comparar nossos arquivos. Subi a minha planilha com o código funcional no endereço https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9We4Z4fXcLcY0pCNjNRRFNwV3M . Verifica o que pode estar acontecendo e retorna pra gente @LucasCarvalho .


Só mais uma dica, depois que der certo, selecione a coluna de resultados e ponha pra ordenar de A à Z, e escolha expandir a seleção. Pronto. Agora você terá os valores __não contidos__ separados dos demais. Bem mais fácil de trabalhar com eles depois.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho se a pergunta foi respondida e resolvida, selecione a resposta que sanou sua dúvida.

Comment: Não é SE.ERRO no caso e sim SEERRO. Deu até certo, mas, ele so verifica se o item na coluna A estive acima do item da coluna B, se não ele vai da como "não"

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65670/discussion-between-gabriel-oliveira-and-lucas-carvalho).

Answer (score 2):

Existe diversas formas de fazer o que pediu, uma delas seria destacar a célula para uma visualização rápida. Minha sugestão é utilizar a formatação condicional da seguinte forma:

1. Selecione a coluna "A" e clique e Formatação Condicional > Nova Regra:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Selecione a opção 1 (da imagem), insira a fórmula abaixo em 2 e formate a célula em 3 conforme desejado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo a Fórmula:

```
=SE(E($A1<>"";ÉERROS(PROCV($A1;B:B;1;FALSO)));VERDADEIRO;FALSO)
```

Esta é uma das formas de fazer, mas como em tudo no Excel, sempre há diversas formas de resolver um mesmo problema, cabe ao gosto de cada um.

Aqui há uma resposta com algo parecido para referência:

[Verificação e Preenchimento de células Excel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235083/verifica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-e-preenchimento-de-c%c3%a9lulas-excel/235102#235102)

Answer (score 0):

A função countif também pode ser utilizada, mas como sei realizar somente em VBA, segue o código. Que pode ser convertido para Função Excel ou ser criado como UDF.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
rLastA = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
rLastB = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To rLastA

    Set c = ws.Cells(i, 1)
    Set rng = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 2), ws.Cells(rLastB, 2))

    x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, c)

    If x < 1 Then Valores = Valores & vbNewLine & c
Next i
MsgBox Valores
```

Pode ser realizado com funções pela lógica de

**Contar SE o valor de uma célula da coluna A é igual ao de todos da coluna B; e depois se o valor do contador é 0(nenhum Match), então retorna o nome do valor da célula da coluna A se não houver match**

Outras formas de realizar com VBA é utilizando `.Find`, `Loop com condicional`, `Loop de Autofiltro` e `Scripting.Dictionary`, sendo que se a planilha é muito grande os dois últimos são mais eficientes.

Answer (score -2):

Tente assim:

Code Snippet

```
Sub excluirvalores()
x = 1
'O loop While corre de celula em celula até a ultima celula preenchida
While Cells(x, 1).Value <> ""
y = x + 1
While Cells(y, 1).Value <> ""
'Verifica se o valor é o mesmo
If Cells(y, 1).Value = Cells(x, 1).Value Then
'exclui a celula se o valor for o mesmo
Cells(y, 1).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If
y = y + 1
Wend
x = x + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Obs:A instrução Cells(x,1) faz referencia à celula A1 se o valor de x for 1, se o valor de x for 2 fará referencia a celula A2.

```
   Para Fazer Referencia à celula B1 mude a Instrução de Cells(x,1) para Cells(x,2) e assim por diante.
```

Espero que ajude

Abraços